# getSymbol of FeatureLayer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, symbology, legend, icon

I'm working with the arcgis javascript API on a webmap.

I have a feature layer on some server which I'm consuming in my webmap and now I want to get the different symbols/icons of that layer one by one in order to display it in a text next to the map (but NOT using the legend widget).
Is that possible? I'm basically looking for something like a featureLayer.getSymbols() function but that doesn't seem to exist.
Any help is greatly appreaciated!

Answer (score 1):

featureLayer.renderer should have all the info you need.

For example, in the console, inspect window.fl.renderer in this sample

http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/samples/data_gas_prices/